# обьясните функцию

Tags: python, telegram-bot

```
def getanekdot():
z=''
s=requests.get('http://anekdotme.ru/random')
b=bs4.BeautifulSoup(s.text, "html.parser")
p=b.select('.anekdot_text')
for x in p:        
    s=(x.getText().strip())
    z=z+s+'\n\n'
return s
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже что это функция, которая парсит страничку, ищет html тэги с классом anekdot_text, получает их текстовое значение и записывает их в array после чего выводит их в консоль. Z нужно для конструкции вывода в консоль

Comment: да это понял а зачем там z = ""

Comment: если надо могу кинуть полный код (это тг бот с анекдотами)

Comment: z нужно для вывода в консоль, в строчке z=z+s+'\n\n' z - суммирует все строчки в одну, s - это текст анекдота, \n\n - две новых строчки

Comment: огромное спасибо бро)